Shortest vector problem as hidden subgroup problem
I posted this question on the cryptography stack exchange with a bounty, but I haven’t gotten much attention. I think part of the reason might be that I’m really interested in the use of group theory in cryptography — not cryptography and computational efficiency per se. For full transparency though, here is a link to the cryptography stack exchange post.
Review of SVP and HSP
SVP: Given a lattice $L$ in a normed vector space $V$, the shortest vector problem asks you to find the point in the lattice with the smallest norm. This is a hard problem, in a certain sense of the word “hard,” and is related to cracking certain lattice-based cryptosystems like NTRU.
HSP: Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a subgroup of $G$, and $f: G \rightarrow X$ a set-map. We say that $f$ hides the subgroup $H$ if for all $a,b \in G$, we have that $f(a) = f(g)$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are in the same coset of $H$. Suppose you’re given an oracle for some $f:G \rightarrow X$, and you know that $f$ is hiding some subgroup $H$ of $G$. The hidden subgroup problem asks if you can efficiently find a generating set for $H$. Here efficiently is barring strategies like “compute $f(g)$ for every $g \in G$.” Several problems that underpin cryptosystems such as factoring and computing discrete logarithms can be viewed as instances of the hidden subgroup problem.
Question
I am interested in whether or not there is a way to directly view the Shortest Vector Problem (SVP) in a finite dimensional lattice as an instance of the Hidden Subgroup Problem (HSP).
Looking around online, I can see that SVP is intimately related to the dihedral hidden subgroup problem. Indeed, Oded Regev has given a quantum reduction from a certain unique shortest vector problem to dihedral coset sampling. The thing is, I’m not particularly interested in the quantum computation aspect — I merely want to understand if SVP can be viewed as a case of HSP, in the same way that other “hard problems” that underpin cryptosystems like factoring and discrete logarithms can.
If I am understanding Regev’s result correctly, such a solution might not be possible. Regev’s reduction from Unique SVP to HSP cannot be carried out efficiently on a classical computer. But it seems that Regev is primarily interested in the quantum aspect and fleshing out a connection between lattice problems and quantum computation. So it could be that there is some other way.
Any resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Can you clarify something for those of us not familiar with these topics? For the HSP, you require $G$ to be a finite group, but the wikipedia article only requires $X$ to be finite. So do you really require $G$ to be finite?

Ahh good catch. $G$ need not be finite, but for computability reasons it’s often handy for it to be. For example, the quantum algorithms used to solve factoring as a hidden subgroup problem uses a superposition over all points in $G$, necessitating that $G$ is finite. But this doesn’t matter for my purposes, and I am more than happy to have an infinite $G$. I have removed the word “finite” from the post.

OK, cool. Some natural groups to think about here could be infinite, but finitely generated. So still something you could work with computationally.

Looks like yes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem. See the 'instance'  table

@GopalAnantharaman So that table doesn’t actually give a reference! The idea that “SVP can be reduced to a dihedral HSP” seems to be oft quoted, but I can’t actually find a reference!

A Characterization. $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a group. Lattice $\mathbf{L}$ is a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$. $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbf{L}$ is defined as $f(\mathbf{a})= \mathbf{a}$, if , $min(\Vert \mathbf{a} \Vert, \lambda) = \lambda$. The left coset that contains $\mathbf{a}$ as a representative is $\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{L} = { \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{v} : \mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{L}}, \mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We are searching for the basis vectors as generators of $\mathbf{L}$. Note that the $X$ from your definition for HSP is $\mathbf{L}$. Isn't this enough? $\lambda$ is minimum norm.

This seems not as simple & I see why people are using dihedral group
